# Pick files next to installer with install4j

Tags: install4j

I have a unix installer with some files included in it and it is working great. Now my requirement is there are some tar files that I dont want to be included in installer as it will become bulky.

So , is it possible with install4j to pick some files that are placed in the same directory as installer and perform actions on them.

If yes, how ? In media we can either include files or place them externally. I want to only include some files.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${installer:sys.installerDir}` resolves to the directory where the installer is located. You can use that expression in all configuration of the installer.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to pick files from installer location .Can we extract a tar.xz file with **Extract a tar** file action  ?  Seems to be not working for me.

Comment: Please ask another question with more details or contact support@ej-technologies.com